# show live TV from a connectted USB DVB-T stick (on windows) on a local web page

Tags: javascript, html, live-streaming, television, webusb

I want to buy a DVB-T stick which gets connect to PC and laptop by USB and has a software to play live TV on windows. What I want to do with that is to show the live TV stream from that stick on a web browser instead of the original windows software. The reason behind that is I need to use it in a digital signage program which only supports web platform for these kind of medias.
As far as I know, if I could make a html page which contains the player to show the live stream from the USB stick, the job is done, but my question is how to write that html page exactly. Any suggestion?

Thanks for paying attention to my question and helping me in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with HTML. Also PHP and JavaScript will not fit this problem. Because that are web based languages. You can not access plugin devices in any way.

The only way you can do is to write an application in C#/C++/Java which will read the usb and open it in a webview to show.

Comment: should that C# application be written for windows? If yes then how can I open it in web?

Comment: I think this should fix your problem: https://cefsharp.github.io/